# How to remove file from git history without commiting changes?

Tags: git

The standard oft-quoted answer is "use filter-branch".

Great. Except ... that fails:

> "Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes."

I'm trying to un-**** git, but git really doesn't want to help here :(. I can't commit changes on some of the files here for a long, long time. The repository is large enough that I can't clone it a second time on this machine (thanks to git's insistence on pulling down massive .git folders for a long-lived project).

Is there a way to simply "remove file X / file-pattern Y" without having to commit everything first? Fundamentally, commiting is an unrelated process (at the user level), so I'm hoping git doesn't conflate the two internally, and there's a way out of this mess.

Comment: I don't understand the exact problem, but I guess you do know `--depth` for clone and `git stash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [stash](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) your changes, which will allow you to do operations like branch filtering, and then re-apply the stashed changes when you're done (although you may have a lot of conflicts afterwards that you'll have to sort out).

I would suggest committing the changes, though. Is there a reason you're making tons of changes without committing them?

Comment: "would suggest committing" if it were that easy, I would have done so.

Comment: If stashing works, that might be OK, although I'm concerned that stashing the changes here could use a lot of diskspace too (the project .git is gigabytes already). Since it was demanding "committed" changes, I assumed stashing wouldn't be good enough.

Comment: I don't have time to test this - it's been a month already - so I'll mark this as accepted answer since it seems correct, but YMMV.